# Constructor on type 'System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView' not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

I just checked out a asp net mvc project from out TFS. After installing all required NuGet packages, I tried to run the project.

I keep getting this error message when trying to use one of the following methods of the MvcSiteMapProvider:

- SiteMapTitle()
- SiteMap()
- SiteMapPath()

I am using .NET Framework 4.0, MVC3 and the MvcSiteMapProvider version 3.2.2.0.

I installed the MvcSiteMapProvider via NuGet (Package Manager Console).

my project references the DLL in ...\packages\MvcSiteMapProvider.3.2.2.0\lib\net40\MvcSiteMapProvider.dll, using Runtime Version v2.0.50727

```
[MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView' not found.]
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +1136
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +111
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +19
MvcSiteMapProvider.Internal.MvcSiteMapProviderViewEngine.CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialPath) +109
System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache) +217
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<FindPartialView>b__7(IViewEngine e) +21
System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths) +127
System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName) +170
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +418
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1117
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +66
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +117
System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +100
System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName) +57
MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapTitleHelper.SiteMapTitle(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper, String templateName) +412
MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapTitleHelper.SiteMapTitle(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper) +33
ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in xxx\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:28
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What .NET version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it to the question

Comment: How have you acquired MvcSiteMapProvider? Nuget? Manual build?

Comment: Could check you references and see if you are referencing the DLL in the net35 or net40 folder?

Comment: That is weird, it should only use `Activator.CreateInstance` on older MVC versions. Could you try the new version 3.2.3.0?

Comment: That worked, if you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks for reacting so fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update to version 3.2.3, then it should work.